# Formatting sdcard failing in linux

Tags: linux

I am trying to format an SanDisk SDHC card [ 16gb ] in linux using fdisk. But it is failing continuously. But the strange thing is that both the partitions, I can use through Dolphin.

My system is 64 bit Kubuntu

I am mentioning the steps which I followed below,

================================================================

```
john@laptop:~/___mp3$ fdisk /dev/sdb1

fdisk: unable to open /dev/sdb1: Permission denied

john@laptop:~/___mp3$ sudo umount /dev/sdb1

[sudo] password for john: 

john@laptop:~/___mp3$ sudo umount /dev/sdb2

john@laptop:~/___mp3$ sudo fdisk  /dev/sdb2
```

You will not be able to write the partition table.
Device contains neither a valid DOS partition table, nor Sun, SGI or OSF disklabel
Building a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0x7cb14dcf.
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
After that, of course, the previous content won't be recoverable.

Warning: invalid flag 0x0000 of partition table 4 will be corrected by w(rite)

Command (m for help): o

Building a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0x8485259f.
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
After that, of course, the previous content won't be recoverable.

Warning: invalid flag 0x0000 of partition table 4 will be corrected by w(rite)

Command (m for help): w

fdisk: unable to write /dev/sdb2: Bad file descriptor

===========================================================

Answer (score 1):

You should call `fdisk` on the whole device, not on a specific partition, so it would be `sudo fdisk /dev/sdb`.

Note that partitioning and formatting are two very different things. Partitioning is an operation to be done on the whole device, to divide it in sections (partitions). Formatting is the act of creating a filesystem on a specific partition, and it is done on the partition, not on the whole device.